# nativescript listview display nothing , it just show after leaving page and coming back

Tags: typescript, api, listview, binding, nativescript

i m new at nativescript and typescript , after navigating to listview page , despite to right iterating object array in console log , listview show nothing , but if i leave the page and navigate back to list page , it works properly 
m using mvvm pattern 
xml view , ts code behind and ts view model 
here view :

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onloaded" class="page body">
<Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar title=" " icon="" class="action-bar  " horizontalAlignment="center">
    </ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>

<StackLayout class="body">
   <AbsoluteLayout width="500" height="40">
        <Image left="435" top="5" src="res://backfinal" class="back" tap="{{onTapBack}}"/>
        <Image left="10" top="5" src="res://off3" class="off" tap="{{onTapLogout}}"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    <Button tap="{{onTap}}" text="back" class="btn btn-primary viewbtn" />

    <ListView id="lstFish" items="{{outFishs}}" margin="15" style="font-size:18;">
        <ListView.itemTemplate >
            <GridLayout columns="*,*" rows="*" margin="10" style="text-align:right;  " class="box ">
                <Label col="0" row="0" text="{{ReceiptNumber}}" style="text-align:right;" class="listEven digit"/>
            </GridLayout >
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

```
export class FishListViewModel extends Observable {private _Fishs: Array<Reciept>;
private _Code: string;
private apiService: ApiService;

ArrayOfFishs: MyReciept[] = [];
constructor() {
    super();
    this.apiService = new ApiService();
    this._Fishs = new Array<Reciept>();
    this.apiService.getReciepts<string>("55809").then(
        (result: MyReciept[]) => {
            var res1 = Object.assign([], result);
            console.log('m in method 2');
            for (var i = 0; i < res1.length; i++) {
                let newRec: MyReciept = <MyReciept>res1[i];
                newRec.PaymentAmount=<any>Common.formatNumber(newRec.PaymentAmount.toString());
                this.ArrayOfFishs.push(newRec);
            }
            console.log('reciepts len ts' + this.ArrayOfFishs.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < this.ArrayOfFishs.length; i++) {
                console.log('in get id 3 rn ts' + i + this.ArrayOfFishs[i]["ReceiptNumber"]);
            }
        });
}

get outFishs(): MyReciept[] {
    console.log('m in getter');
    console.log('this._Fishs.len:' + this.ArrayOfFishs.length);
    this.notifyPropertyChange('outFishs', this.ArrayOfFishs);
    return this.ArrayOfFishs;
}
public init() {
}

public onTap() {
    console.log('m in tap');
     Navigation.goToMember();
}
```

}

ts code behind of xml view

```
import { EventData, Observable, fromObject } from "tns-core-modules/data

/observable";import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { FishListViewModel } from './FishList-view-model'
import { ApiService } from '../../services/ApiService'
import { ItemEventData, ListView } from "tns-core-modules/ui/list-view";
import { MyReciept } from '../../shared/Interfaces'
import * as Navigation from '../../shared/Navigation'

var vm = new FishListViewModel();
var api = new ApiService();
var fishs: MyReciept[] = [];
export function onloaded(args: EventData) {
    let page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = vm;
    vm.init();
}
```

ofcourse i must remind at first time in viewmodel i put my api function call in "init" , it showed nothing but when i put call function in structure part it works after renavigate ...
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved the problem 
actually i was notifying the UI with wrong code

```
 this.notify({object:this , eventName:Observable.propertyChangeEvent , propertyName:'outFishs',value:this.outFishs})
```

the correct code is :

```
this.notify({object:this , eventName:ObservableArray.propertyChangeEvent , propertyName:'outFishs',value:this.outFishs})
```

and also at outFishs getter i put this code before return

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.ArrayOfFishs.length; i++) {
            this.notifyPropertyChange('outFishs', this.ArrayOfFishs[i]);
        }
```

and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel becomes a singleton as its scooped global to the TS file and created only once when that TS file is loaded first time.

The API call is asynchronous, so you are suppose to call `notifyPropertyChange` inside your API call back, may be right after your logs.

It's working for the second time as the array is already loaded from previous visit.

Comment: hi tnx for answer , i did this too i put code in api call after feeding array but it does not work         this.notify({ object: this, eventName: Observable.propertyChangeEvent, propoertyName: outFishs, value: this.ArrayOfFishs });        i have another page that feed by one object i used notify and it worked but here i have an array of object it doesnot work